# PowerShell Import-Csv Issue - Why is my output being treated as a single column and not a CSV?

Tags: powershell, csv

So I have a CSV file which I need to manipulate a bit, select the data I need and export to another CSV file.

The code I have is:

```
$rawCSV = "C:\Files\raw.csv"
$outputCSV = "C:\Files\output.csv"

Import-Csv -Header @("a","b","c","d") -Path $rawCSV  |
select -Skip 7 |
Where-Object { $_.b.length -gt 1 } |
ft b,a,c,d |
Out-File $outputCSV
```

So this code uses the Import-Csv command to allow me to select just the columns I need, add some headers in the order I want and then I am simply putting the output in to a CSV file called $outputCSV. The contents of this output file look something like this:

```
b         a         c         d
-         -         -         -
john      smith     29        England
mary      poopins   79        Walton
```

I am not sure what the delimiter is in this output and rather than these columns being treated as individuals, they are treated as just one column. I have gone on further to replace all the spaces with a comma using the code:

```
$b = foreach ($line in $a)
{
    $fields = $line -split '`n'
    foreach ($field in $fields)
    {
        $field -replace " +",","
    }
}
```

Which produces a file that looks like this:

```
b,a,c,d
john,smith,29,England
mary,poppins,79,Walton
```

But these are all still treated as one column instead of four separate columns as I need.

*** UPDATE ***

Using the answer given by @, I now get a file looking like this:

[image]

Comment: the output looks like csv format, what program are you viewing the output in that says it is one column ?

Comment: If I view the output in Excel or in an SQL table it displays as one column.

Comment: if i save your sample output and open it in excel I see 4 columns as expected

Comment: I know. If I open the file in Wordpad for example, copy all the data and paste into excel, I see four columns as expected. But directly opening the file in Excel, I see one column... I think it has to be to do with the `Import-Csv` command treating the data unexpectedly along the way...

Comment: you could look to see if there are any non-printing characters in the file that may be confusing things  -http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/get-hex-dumps-files-powershell

Comment: Thanks @Ian Kenney. I will certainly have a look at this.

Comment: Why aren't you using Export-csv?  That's the easy way to convert an internal data structure, like an array of hashtables, into a csv file.

Comment: @Walter Thanks. I was attempting to use Export-Csv but kept getting errors in  the output. However the answer below uses Export-Csv and is working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `ft` to reorder your columns - it's intended to format output for the screen, not really suitable for CSV.

## "Manual" solution:

```
$rawCSV = "C:\Files\raw.csv"
$outputCSV = "C:\Files\output.csv"

# Import and filter your raw data
$RawData = Import-Csv -Header @("a","b","c","d") -Path $rawCSV  
$Data    = $RawData | Select -Skip 7 | Where-Object { $_.b.length -gt 1 }

# Write your headers to the output file
"b","a","c","d" -join ',' | Out-File $outputCSV -Force

$ReorderedData = foreach($Row in $Data){
    # Reorder the columns in each row 
    '{0},{1},{2},{3}' -f $Row.b , $Row.a , $Row.c, $Row.d
}

# Write the reordered rows to the output file
$ReorderedData | Out-File $outputCSV -Append
```

---

## Using `Export-Csv`:

As of PowerShell 3.0, you could also push the rows into a `[pscustomobject]` and pipe that to `Export-Csv` (`pscustomobject` preserves the order in which you supply the properties):

```
$rawCSV = "C:\Files\raw.csv"
$outputCSV = "C:\Files\output.csv"

# Import and filter your raw data
$RawData = Import-Csv -Header @("a","b","c","d") -Path $rawCSV  
$Data    = $RawData | Select -Skip 7 | Where-Object { $_.b.length -gt 1 }

# Take the columns you're interested in, put them into new custom objects and export to CSV
$Data | ForEach-Object { 
    [pscustomobject]@{ "b" = $_.b; "a" = $_.a; "c" = $_.c; "d" = $_.d } 
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $outputCSV
```

`Export-Csv` will take care of enclosing strings in quotes to escape ',' properly (one thing less for you to worry about)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have uploaded an image of the output given from your code in my UPDATE above.

Comment: @Johnathan Yes, sorry about that, forgot to write the headers as a single string. Please see the update. I've also included a safer alternative using `Export-Csv`

Comment: @Johnathan Note that for Excel to open the CSV correctly you need to export the CSV with the delimiter set to list separator character defined in the system's region settings.

Comment: @Johnathan ++ What Ansger said, otherwise you'll need to configure import settings with the Data Import wizard in Excel

Comment: @Mathias The "Manual Solution" you suggested still treats the columns as one column instead of four and I am unsure why that is. However, the "Export-Csv" solution works great for me so thank you. Ansgar, Thanks I will make sure to do that :)

Comment: @Johnathan When you say "still treats the columns as one", you are refering to Excel, right? See the comments above

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what your raw CSV file looks like? If it's already like this

```
john,smith,29,England
mary,poppins,79,Walton
```

then `import-csv` will give you an array of objects which you can easily manipulate (and objects are the main reason to use PowerShell ;). For example, to check what you have after import:

```
$r = Import-Csv -Path $rawCSV -Header @("b","a","c","d") 
$r.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                              
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

$r[0] | get-member

TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
a           NoteProperty System.String a=smith         
b           NoteProperty System.String b=john          
c           NoteProperty System.String c=29            
d           NoteProperty System.String d=England
```

For now you have array of objects with properties named "a","b","c","d". To manipulate objects you have `select-object` cmdlet:

```
$r | Select-Object a,b,c,d

a         b        c        d                                          
-         -        -        -                                          
smith   john       29    England                                    
poppins mary       79    Walton
```

And after all use `export-csv` to set the output file:

```
$r | where { $_.b.length -gt 1 } | 
 select a,b,c,d | 
 Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 -path $outputCSV
```

I could think of two possible reasons why your data teated as one column:

1. consuming application expect different encoding and can't find
   delimiters
2. delimiters are not commas but something else